# How to know Form is selected or not in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I created a child form from parents form.

How to know the child form is selected?

In other words how to know specific form status bar is now blue or not?

Because I want to know child form is selected or not.

like this

```
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    public ChildForm()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void Fuction1()
    {
        if (ThisFormIsSelect)
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "is select(ed)"? Do you mean that it has the focus? How did you open the child from the parent? And what has any status-bar to do with the issue? Your question is completely unclear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would call/use the Form.Activated event. Something like this (note, might not compile and you might need to add the eventhanlder bind yourself):

```
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    private bool _isFormActive;
    public ChildForm()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void Fuction1()
    {
        if (_isFormActive)
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }

private void ChildForm1_Activated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    _isFormActive = true;
}
private void ChildForm1_Deactivated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    _isFormActive = false;
}
}
```